# Choice of verb in statements of existence

Tags: verb-usage

The following sentences, which I have taken from some simple texts, appear be about the existence (or non-existence) of something:

> Heute ist viel Verkehr.
>
> In meinem Kurs sind acht Schülerinnen und fünf Schüler.
>
> Heute gibt es Hähnchen. Das nehme ich.
>
> Es gibt keine Eintrittskarten mehr.
>
> Dort gibt es günstige Angebote.
>
> Es gibt viele Probleme auf der Welt.
>
> Die Fahrkarten gibt es nur am Automaten.

The first two sentences use a construction with the verb *sein*; the remainder use *es gibt*. Could they just as easily be switched around without altering the meaning? Could the idea in the second sentence, for example, have been expressed as

> In meinem Kurs ***gibt es*** acht Schülerinnen und fünf Schüler.

Could the idea in the final sentence have been expressed as:

> Die Fahrkarten ***sind*** nur am Automaten.

If the answer is that they could have been expressed using the alternative construction, what might influence a native speaker to put an idea one way rather than the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, those constructions cannot be used in exchange for another.

In some of your examples, *es gibt* indicates that someone gets something or that something is provided:

> Dort gibt es günstige Angebote.

> Es gibt keine Eintrittskarten mehr.

> Heute gibt es Hähnchen.

> Die Fahrkarten gibt es nur am Automaten.

In these cases, it would be incorrect to replace *es gibt* with a form of *sein*.

There is another use case of *es gibt*, which would be translated as "there is". Here, *es gibt* could be replaced with a form of *sein*:

> Auf der Welt sind viele Probleme.

However the form with the expletive *es* (*Es sind viele Probleme auf der Welt*) is not idiomatic.

Comment: In the second example the subject is *acht Schülerinnen und fünf Schüler*; it says something about students, which implies that they exist, but that's not actually stated. In the first example I'm not sure what the subject is, *heute* or *viel Verkehr*; the sentence seems strange either way. Regardless, the same logic applies, making a statement about something implies the "something" exists without actually stating it. (In natural language at least, formal logic might be different. Saying things like "If I exist then I am hungry," would get tiresome.)